# ES timeout after upgrade on a single cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, netty

So I've had ES version 0.19.4 and wanted to upgrade to 0.20.6 as my clusters didn't have any information that I couldn't easily recover I deleted the indices's and completely cleared down my es data folder, removed the 0.19.4 version and as I start up I somehow cannot use my original cluster name, the ES starts fine with any other cluster name but not with "aggr" the one I used before, as I wanted to make sure nothing else is using old Elastic Search I even rebooted the computer (don't have any on startup software on this test system) so essentially everything is clear but I can't use the old cluster name... The stack:

```
[2013-04-03 13:37:59,902][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Orchid] failed to connect to requesting node [Kaur, Benazir][by0TZFhXR1mUxBd9T6bi9w][inet[/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx]]{client=true, data=false}
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Kaur, Benazir][inet[/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx]] connect_timeout[30s]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:671)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:610)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:580)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:127)
at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$Receiver$1.run(MulticastZenPing.java:536)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processConnectTimeout(NioClientBoss.java:136)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:82)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:41)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
... 3 more
```

All of the elasticsearch.yml settings are commented out apart from:

```
cluster.name: aggr
```

Also when Elastic Search starts on my testing machine which is connected on internal network I see in the logs:

```
[2013-04-03 13:37:27,281][INFO ][node                     ] [Orchid] {0.20.6}[4484]: initializing ...
[2013-04-03 13:37:27,287][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Orchid] loaded [], sites []
[2013-04-03 13:37:29,633][INFO ][node                     ] [Orchid] {0.20.6}[4484]: initialized
[2013-04-03 13:37:29,633][INFO ][node                     ] [Orchid] {0.20.6}[4484]: starting ...
[2013-04-03 13:37:29,710][INFO ][transport                ] [Orchid] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/**My internal IP**:9300]}
[2013-04-03 13:37:32,739][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Orchid] new_master [Orchid][MzSRtsCfR2W3S_QyG_QLQg][inet[/**My internal IP**:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2013-04-03 13:37:32,818][INFO ][discovery                ] [Orchid] aggr/MzSRtsCfR2W3S_QyG_QLQg
[2013-04-03 13:37:32,857][INFO ][http                     ] [Orchid] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/**My internal IP**:9200]}
[2013-04-03 13:37:32,857][INFO ][node                     ] [Orchid] {0.20.6}[4484]: started
[2013-04-03 13:37:32,945][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Orchid] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

And in the error log right afterwards I see the log for my server machine which is connected with and external IP:

```
[2013-04-03 13:37:59,902][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Orchid] failed to connect to requesting node [Kaur, Benazir][by0TZFhXR1mUxBd9T6bi9w][inet[/**My external IP**:9301]]{client=true, data=false}
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Kaur, Benazir][inet[/**My external IP**:9301]] connect_timeout[30s]
```

How can this be? How can my system start on my internal machine and throw an error linking to my external machine? Again the only setting set in the ES.yml is the cluster name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you still have old client node running somewhere:

```
[Kaur, Benazir][inet[/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xxxx]]
```

You need to shut it down before starting the cluster with the new version.

This client is probably running in your web application that is using elasticsearch an while you upgraded elasticsearch server, you didn't upgrade elasticsearch library in this application. Do you have any java app running on xxx.xxx.xx.xxx? Try shutting it down.

Comment: That's what I thought was happening, the problem is I only run ES on my localhost and restarted a couple of times to make sure all the programs get killed. And none of them automatically start up :/ Main reason why I'm asking..

Comment: My typical approach to starting my apps is start ES>start app> close app> stop ES. And yes I made sure all the webapps of mine that use elastic search are killed, as I said restarted couple times as well. :/ I'm in a pickle, I know your answer should be correct, I had the same feeling after doing some digging.. Still can't identify the problem though.

Comment: Try this, shut everything down and try running `curl  xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:yyyy` where yyyy is port in the log - 100. So, if it was 9300, try connecting to 9200. Do you get back a response?

Comment: okay, so it doesn't return anything, just hangs, however I noticed something different when the elasticsearch starts I get weird info in the loggs, they slipped by me, I will edit my post in a second

Comment: Kaur, Benazir is a client node. Do you have some stale instance of your web app running? Try killing all java processing on you machine.

Comment: I have an Elastic Search instance running on my external server but how should that intervene the startup of an elastic search instance on an internal machine that is trying to host on a localhost? I never had this problem before.

Comment: Can your external machine receive multicast packets from your internal machine?

Comment: I do not know this but I got about 7 machines rigged onto that one and none of them had any problems with each and individual locally hosted Elastic Search, how would that change things? As I said the only change made was the version of ES.

Comment: p.s. I'm really glad you're helping me, not many people out there comment on ES threads.

Comment: Changing version is a big deal. Elasticsearch nodes with different versions shouldn't be combined into the same cluster. And you cannot run two elasticsearch clusters with the same cluster name but different versions on the same network unless you turn off multicast, which is clearly enabled on this machine.